# how to install mssql 2008 r2 from iso

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to install ms sql from iso. I've installed virtual clonedrive which mounts the iso as drive however i'm getting the following error.

E:\Resoourse\1033\setup.rll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains and error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator

what is the best method to install ms sql from iso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you run a hash on the ISO image and make sure is not corrupted. Extracting the contents is fruitless if you have some corrupt data as is only going to waste your time.

I would suggest you use [HashTab](http://beeblebrox.org/) to generate the HASH for your ISO and compare that to the Microsoft download page.

SHA1 sums for TechNet/MSDN Media:

- 18105DB70F0F0B23418F5005A6CE4B25317C6D03 (en_sql_server_2008_r2_enterprise_x86_x64_ia64_dvd_520517.iso)
- 09CF52A4209CA96FF480537BB86786F79AE0E8A3 (en_sql_server_2008_r2_standard_x86_x64_ia64_dvd_521546.iso)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you had a dvd drive or not, but if you do then burn the iso file to a dvd using [isoburn](http://sourceforge.net/projects/isoburn/) or the like and try installing it again.

Answer (score 0):

Or use 7-Zip to extract the ISO, and install from the folder it extracts to.

http://7-zip.org/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue.  The issue is the Windows machine was not up-to-date on all the updates.  First the computer did not have Internet access and that had to be resolved.  Once I got Internet Access I spent 1 hour downloading Windows Updates.

After the Updates were all installed.  Everything worked.